# Problem getting mod-wsgi to run an app written using python3

Tags: python, flask, mod-wsgi

I've been hacking away at this for a couple weeks now.  I got mod_wsgi working using these [instructions](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-flask-application-on-an-ubuntu-vps) and and [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YFBRVJPhDGY).

When I used what I had learned to put my own application into play on my web-server, I had some problems but worked through most of them.  The "stopper" was that I had written my application for Python 3.6 and the imports caused errors because mod_wsgi was trying to run them with Python 2.7.  Further study made me aware that I needed to install `libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3` instead of `libapache2-mod-wsgi`.  At least, that's what I thought from what I read [here](http://terokarvinen.com/2017/write-python-3-web-apps-with-apache2-mod_wsgi-install-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-every-tiny-part-tested-separately).

Now, I have a new error:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-26-13-175:~$ sudo systemctl start apache2
Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Based on that, I try:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-26-13-175:~$ sudo systemctl status apache2.service
● apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
           └─apache2-systemd.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2020-06-30 18:44:53 UTC; 14s ago
  Process: 6773 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jun 30 18:44:53 ip-172-26-13-175 systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Jun 30 18:44:53 ip-172-26-13-175 apachectl[6773]: AH00526: Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/mod-wsgi.conf:
Jun 30 18:44:53 ip-172-26-13-175 apachectl[6773]: Invalid command 'WSGIScriptAlias', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
Jun 30 18:44:53 ip-172-26-13-175 apachectl[6773]: Action 'start' failed.
Jun 30 18:44:53 ip-172-26-13-175 apachectl[6773]: The Apache error log may have more information.
Jun 30 18:44:53 ip-172-26-13-175 systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jun 30 18:44:53 ip-172-26-13-175 systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jun 30 18:44:53 ip-172-26-13-175 systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
```

Based on that I check:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-26-13-175:~$ cat /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/mod-wsgi.conf
WSGIScriptAlias /test_wsgi /var/www/html/wsgi_test_script.py
```

And based on that, I check to see if the target of that alias exists and has valid code:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-26-13-175:~$ cat /var/www/html/wsgi_test_script.py
def application(environ,start_response):
    status = '200 OK'
    html = '<html>\n' \
           '<body>\n' \
           ' Hooray, mod_wsgi is working\n' \
           '</body>\n' \
           '</html>\n'
    response_header = [('Content-type','text/html')]
    start_response(status,response_header)
    return [html]
```

Since everything checks out, I don't know how to solve the problem.  I don't even know what to check next.  Obviously, my Flask/mod_wsgi app isn't going to work if I can't start Apache.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

I simply disabled the conf that was causing the problem with:

```
sudo a2disconf mod-wsgi.conf
```

Apache starts perfectly now.